# XSL looping against nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes

i need to create a XSLT that could manage two differnts forms like the following ones:

```
<form>
<requestor>rqu </requestor>
<pp1>pepe1<pp2>

</form>

<form>
<requestor>rqu </requestor>
<pp1>pepe1<pp1>
    <pp2>pepe2<pp2>
</form>
```

The idea is to loop between all the nodes and output the information as following:

**for first example**

requestor -> rqu

pp1 -> pepe1

**second example**

requestor -> rqu

pp1 -> pepe1

pp2 -> pepe 2

Is an easy question but i dont know how to obtain the node name and loop nodes, i was searching and i didnt get nothing related...

Comment: That's not valid XML. Specifially, this part: `<pp1>pepe1<pp2>` and this part: `<pp1>pepe1<pp1>
    <pp2>pepe2<pp2>`. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a very simple XML structure as shown, you could write something like this to simply loop over the child elements of the `form` element

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="form">
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
          <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
          <xsl:text> -> </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is working, finally was a problem of xmlEditor (xmlSpy), i dont know why but i tried it in an online application and its working fine. Any free application recommendable please?

Answer (score 0):

> Is an easy question but i dont know how to obtain the node name and
>   loop nodes, i was searching and i didnt get nothing related...

Use either the `name()` or the `local-name()` function to get the node name.
Use either `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:apply-templates` instruction to traverse the nodes.